# How to make box light up in navigation bar - CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make the box that the lettering is in light up instead of the actual lettering on my sites navigation bar, [My site](http://mavenpvp.cu.cc).

If you could tell me where and how I can edit the code to achieve the desired results it would be very helpful.

NOTE: Take in mind I am a web design newbie.

This is the code layout.css code and index.html code:
**layout.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/bg_main.png);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Logo;
    src: url(font/minecraft_font_by_pwnage_block-d37t6nb.ttf);
}

#header {
    background:#8cbeff;
    background-image: url(../img/180px-Sun.png), url(../img/bg-outside-clouds.png);
    background-position: center right, top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    width: 990px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#logo h1 {
    color: #222;
    text-shadow:0 0 30px #333;
}

#logo h1:before {
    content:"Maven";   /* Yellow Text */
    color: yellow;
    font-family: Logo;
}

#logo h1:after {
    content: "PVP";  /* Black Text */
    font-family: Logo;
}

#nav {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    background-color:#2b2b2b;
    border-bottom:4px solid #444442;
    font-size:15px;
    height:36px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; 
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #666;
    border-top: 10px solid #009514;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    }

#nav_holder {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

#nav_holder ul.right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#nav_holder li.first {
    margin-left: -30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 #000 inset, -1px 0 #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 #000 inset, -1px 0 #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 #000 inset, -1px 0 #000 inset; 
    text-shadow:0 0 1px #000;
}


#nav_holder li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 #000 inset;  
    text-shadow:0 0 1px #000;
}

#nav_holder li a {
    line-height: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    transition: color .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .2s linear;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: yellow;
    font-family: Logo;
}
#nav_holder li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #00a5f0; 
    transition: color .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: color .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: grow .1s linear;
}

#nav_holder li a:active {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #000;
    width: 300px;
}

/* Now the header is done */


/* Main Content */

.sub_header {
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 105px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: url(../img/planks.jpg);
    border: 4px solid #56472A; 
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 3px #333; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -2px 3px #333; 
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 3px #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
}

.announcement {
    background: #7f9db9;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 1020px;
    position: relative;
    left: -29px;
    top: 20px;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    z-index: 100;
}

.announcement ul#items {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.triangle-l {
    border-color: transparent #7d90a3 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    left: -44px;
    top: 55px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.triangle-r {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7d90a3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 974px;
    top: 27px;
    z-index: -1; 
}

#content_container {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 2px inset black;
    border-bottom: 2px outset black;
    background-image:url(../img/sidebar.png);
    width: 249px;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Sanchez', serif;
}

.sidebar h3.address {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.sidebar div.online {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: -36px;;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px green;
}

.sidebar div.offline {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: -36px;;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px red;
}

.sidebar p.address {
    color: green;
}

.right_content {
    background-image:url(../img/right_content.png);
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 4px solid #222;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(000, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px rgba(000, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px rgba(000, 0, 0, 1);
    width: 660px;
    color: #999;
}

.right_content h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.right_content h1 {
    color: #999;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #222;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.footer {
    text-align: Center;
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Site Title -->
<title>Minecraft</title>

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/layout.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sanchez' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!-- Google Font (Replace with own if needed) -->

<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="js/jquery00.js"></script>
<script src="js/ticker00.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#items').list_ticker({
            speed:5000,
            effect:'fade'
        }); 
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Site Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1></h1> <!-- Site's Title on line 36 and 42 in layout.css  -->
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->

    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_holder">

            <ul>
                <li class="first"><a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
                <li><a href="rules.html"> Rules </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Help </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Forum </a> </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="right">
                <li class="first"><a href="#"> Sign Up! </a> </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>


        <!-- Main Content -->

        <div class="sub_header">


        <!-- Announcements Ribbon -->

        <div class="announcement">
                <ul id="items">

                <!-- Replace these with your messages -->

                <li>Server's site was made by sgt_awes0me</li>
                <li>Sign up on the forums now!</li>
                <li>Here is another one. This one is a little bit longer</li>
                <li>Server's Ip is 555.5555.5555:55555</li>

            </ul>

        </div>
         <!-- Creates the ribbon feel -->
        <div class="triangle-l"></div>
        <div class="triangle-r"></div>

        </div>

        <!-- End of Header and Sub-Header -->


        <!--
        ====================================
            Now The Main Content Begins
        ====================================
        -->


        <!-- Content Container -->

        <div id="content_container">


        <!-- Right Content -->

        <div class="right_content">

            <h1> Welcome! </h1> <!-- Title -->


            <!-- This is dummy text. You can change it to whatever you like -->
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lacinia lorem blandit erat bibendum pharetra. In odio sapien, sodales in tempus nec, feugiat a ante. Sed tincidunt vestibulum lacus at posuere. Nulla metus justo, pretium in tempor a, condimentum non metus. Suspendisse enim velit, rhoncus eu vehicula ut, molestie non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent rutrum, lacus ut condimentum dapibus, leo enim faucibus lectus, a dictum lacus ipsum non nulla. Maecenas tempus magna quis nunc aliquam sit amet venenatis felis vulputate. Fusce vel nisl odio, eget suscipit tellus.

Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam hendrerit sagittis posuere. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Sed imperdiet enim in diam venenatis vel faucibus velit vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse mauris quam, porta molestie volutpat et, consectetur eu nisi. Etiam at risus massa, non accumsan tortor. Sed tortor ligula, rhoncus eget fermentum ut, tincidunt eu tortor. Quisque urna lectus, posuere iaculis tempor id, lobortis sed dui. Vivamus ultricies luctus eros non molestie. Nunc vitae erat lectus. Proin elit lectus, cursus et cursus ac, posuere porta felis. Ut vitae felis et ipsum vulputate convallis. Proin tincidunt orci a dolor congue ut tempor quam egestas.</p>

        <div class="footer">

        <p>Copyright &copy; 2012 - Server Name 

        </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Sidebar. You can either have one long sidebar or multiple "widgets" -->

        <div class="sidebar">

        <h3 class="address">Server Address</h3>
        <p class="address">555.5555.555:25565</p>

        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">

                        <!-- Change To Online or Offline depending on your server status -->
        <h3>Server Status: </h3> <div class="offline"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">

        <h3> Example Header </h3>
        <p>This is where you can put a server description or anything else!</p>
        <h3>

        </h3>

        </div>  
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the a tags around the li: this allows the user to click anywhere in the box, and might solve your problem.

Comment: @CSGregorian so:
<a href="rules.html"><li> Rules </li> </a>
?

Comment: Yeah; you'll have to change your css to affect that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#nav_holder li:hover { background: white; }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I just don't know how to edit it to make the box light up.

Comment: You can put it anywhere in layout.css, preferably after this rule "#nav_holder li".

Comment: Thats just what I needed! Thanks!